# Issue in generating Oauth Client and requesting access token via code in Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I am using Passport Authentication API in Laravel 5.3. I have created two routes one for generating oauth clients and second for requesting access_token. But I am getting NULL value from `/gen_client` route and showing login page from `/redirect` route.

*Can anyone please help me in this?*

```
Route::get('/gen_client', function () {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client();    
    $response = $http->post(url('/') . '/oauth/clients', [          
        'form_params' => [
            'id' => 'ok@test.com',
            'name' => 'OK',
            'redirect' => url('/') . '/callback'
        ],
    ]); 
    $response_body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);  
    var_dump($response_body);
}); 

Route::get('/redirect', function () {
    $oauth_client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', '=', 'ok@test.com')->first();  
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => $oauth_client->id,
        'redirect_uri' => $oauth_client->redirect,
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);

    return redirect(url('/') . '/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});

Route::post('callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client();  
    $oauth_client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', '=', 'ok@test.com')->first();   
    $response = $http->post(url('/') . '/oauth/token', [        
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $oauth_client->id,
            'client_secret' => $oauth_client->secret,
            'redirect_uri' => url('/') . '/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);  
    $response_body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);  
    var_dump($response_body);
    $access_token = $response_body['access_token'] ;  
    $refresh_token = $response_body['refresh_token'];  
}
```

);

Comment: Your `gen_client` route is returning nothing, therefore `NULL`. Also, the `id` parameter is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gen_client` route is returning nothing, therefore it will return `NULL`.

You are also confusing things somewhat by trying to introduce your own *ID* and use the `oauth_clients` table directly.

The call to POST /oauth/clients will return a payload which includes the client's *ID* and *Secret*.

You then put those values into *config* somewhere, and use them like this (along with other parameters required for the call you're making):

```
[
    'client_id' => config('services.myoauth.client_id'),
    'client_secret' => config('services.myoauth.client_secret'),
]
```

Don't access the `oauth_clients` tables directly, that's the *OAuth* server's job.

Creating clients is (usually) a manual thing that is done *once* when connecting an OAuth client webapp to an OAuth server.